# UICollectionView - customize item disappearing when section collapses

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, sections, flowlayout

I collapse & expand sections by toggling `numberOfItemsInSection:`. When collapsing, items disappear through alpha fade-out. I would like to change this effect to scaling them down.

I think I can implement this with custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and overloaded `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`. But when section collapses, `numberOfItemsInSection:` returns 0 - so I can't set destination scale for that items.

What is correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found approach: we need to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and override `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:`

For example:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];
    attributes.frame = CGRectInset(attributes.frame, 20, 20);
    return attributes;
}
```